# if-statement with .get-operator in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the class of a dl-element. I can print the class (see the first line) but i cant use that result in an if-statement (So "works" is never printed). 
I guess i am somehow wrong with my syntax. Am i?
Believe me that there are lot of "method"-class elements in my tests - see below

```
 print(child.dl.get('class'))
    if child.dl.get('class')=="['method']":
        print("WORKS!")
```

This is the output of the first line:

```
['method']
['method']
['class']
['method']
['method']
['method']
['method']
['describe']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`child.dl.get('class')` returns a `list` since `class` is a [`multi-valued attribute`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes).

Check if `method` is inside the list:

```
if 'method' in child.dl.get('class', []):
    print("WORKS!")
```